# Haskell cast Integer to Int

Tags: haskell, casting, integer

Why the first one is correct and the second one isn't?
I'd like to implement the code in the second way so that I won't have to call every time fromInteger, but I don't understand how...

Correct

```
bits :: Integer -> Int 
bits 0 = 0
bits n = fromInteger n `mod` 2 + bits(fromInteger n `div` 2)
```

Incorrect

```
bits :: Integer -> Int 
bits 0 = 0
bits n = let m = fromInteger n in m `mod` 2 + bits(m `div` 2)
```

Comment: The safe version would actually be ``bits n = fromInteger (n`mod`2) + bits (n`div`2)``. Alternatively ``case n`divMod`2 of (q,r) -> fromInteger r + bits q``.

Comment: How is calling `bits` better than simply calling `fromInteger`? Aside from using more CPU cycles, `bits` *is* `fromInteger`. You're basically converting `12 :: Integer` to `12 :: Int` by recognizing that `12 == 8 + 4`, then adding `8` and `4` to get back `12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reason that this version doesn't typecheck:

```
bits :: Integer -> Int
bits 0 = 0
bits n = let m = fromInteger n in m `mod` 2 + bits(m `div` 2)
```

First, note that the first usage of `m` requires that `m` be an `Int` because the result of a `bits` call must be an `Int` which means the left hand side of the addition (namely `` m `mod` 2 ``) must be an `Int`.  Why is this?  Well, it's because the signature of the `+` operator is:

```
(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

which requires both arguments of `+` to have the same type as its result.  Similarly, because `` m `mod` 2 `` must be an `Int`, the left hand side of the `` `mod` `` call (namely `m`) must be an `Int`, because `mod` has signature:

```
mod :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
```

So, that's why the first usage of `m` requires `m :: Int`.  Whew!

For much the same reason, the **second** usage of `m` requires that `m` be an `Integer`.  That's because the argument to `bits` in the expression `` bits (m `div` 2) `` must be an `Integer` which requires that the left hand side of the `` `div` `` operator must be an `Integer`.

Therefore, we have a requirement that `m` be both an `Int` and an `Integer`.  This isn't necessarily a problem.  If you had instead written:

```
bits :: Integer -> Int
bits 0 = 0
bits n = m `mod` 2 + bits(m `div` 2)
  where m :: (Integral a) => a
        m = fromInteger n
```

and given `m` an explicit polymorphic type signature, then `m` could be used as both an `Int` and and `Integer` simultaneously.  However, because of something called the monomorphism restriction, without an explicit type signature, `m` is required to have a single non-polymorphic (i.e., monomorphic type).  If you add the pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

to the top of your file, then the original definition typechecks fine:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

bits :: Integer -> Int
bits 0 = 0
bits n = let m = fromInteger n in m `mod` 2 + bits(m `div` 2)
```

Others have noted, though, that you don't actually need `fromInteger` in both places; and that using `Int` and `Integer` simultaneously is unnecessary, and using a single integer type with a constraint (`Integral a`) *might* be even better.

Also, if you wanted this function for real work instead of just practice, it's already available as `popCount` in module `Data.Bits`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't need it for the 2nd call:

```
bits :: Integer -> Int 
bits 0 = 0
bits n = fromInteger n `mod` 2 + bits (n `div` 2)
```

The 2nd `fromInteger` simply resulted in `Integer` again, as forced by the parameter to `bits`.

Answer (score 1):

You may perhaps tweak the signature a little bit and get rid of all `fromInteger`s.

```
bits :: Integral a => a -> a 
bits 0 = 0
bits n = n `mod` 2 + bits (n `div` 2)
```

Comment: But the original signature makes sense actually, because this function can break huge numbers down to a small digest.